# How can this sum from 1 to infinity be equal to an integral from 0 to 2?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am currently doing the final exam of the MIT OCW Calculus 1 course and got stuck on evaluating a limit, I went to the solutions to get a hint, but can't even quite understand how the solution works, more specifically the first step where the sum is said to be equal to the integral. Why are these two equal?

$\displaystyle{\left[\lim_{{{n}\rightarrow\infty}}{\sum_{{{i}={1}}}^{{{n}}}}\sqrt{{{1}+\frac{{{2}{i}}}{{{n}}}}}{\left(\frac{{{2}}}{{{n}}}\right)},={\int_{{{0}}}^{{{2}}}}\sqrt{{{1}+{x}}}{\left.{d}{x}\right.}\right]}$

Comment: Imagine that you have $n$ rectangles, each of width $2/n$, distributed in the 
$[0,2]$ interval.  The right hand corner locations of these rectangles are 
$x = (2i/n),$ as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$ and the height of these rectangles is $$\sqrt{1 + \frac{2i}{n}}.$$
Therefore, the LHS summation, ignoring the limit, represents the area of these
$n$ rectangles.  As $n \to \infty$, the unfilled space between $f(x)$ and the 
rectangles goes to zero.  Therefore, the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of these $n$ 
rectangles, (of narrower and narrower width) equals the RHS integral.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is [a Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_sums) for that integral for a uniform partition $[0,2/n,4/n,\ldots,1]$. Thus, in the limit it becomes the integral by definition of a Riemann integral.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle{{\sum_{{{i}={1}}}^{{{n}}}}\sqrt{{{1}+\frac{{{2}{i}}}{{{n}}}}}{\left(\frac{{{2}}}{{{n}}}\right)}}$ is a Riemann sum for the integral

$${\int_{{{0}}}^{{{2}}}}\sqrt{{{1}+{x}}}{\left.{d}{x}\right.},$$

with the partition $\{\frac{2i}{n}: i=0,1,...,n\}$ of $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the summation conceptually, consider

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$$

Now, we look at a particular term in the sum

$$T(i) = \sqrt{1+\frac{2i}{n}}\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) = \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2i}{n}}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{2(i+1)}{n} - \frac{2i}{n}\right)$$

This is essentially an approximation of the area of the rectangle with dimensions

$$H = \sqrt{1+\frac{2i}{n}}$$

$$W = \frac{2}{n}$$

Now as you make $n$ larger and larger, you are essentially narrowing this rectangular strip - and in the limiting case you are essentially integrating the area under the function $f(x)$ from $0$ to $2$